# Objects attributes contain values before instatiaton

Tags: python, django

Inside Django I do have:

```
class A(object):
    _attribute = []
```

When I create the object while executing a request to the `Django.runserver` everything works fine. During this step I fill `a = A()._attribute.extend(['string',])`.

When I execute the same request the second time I see BEFORE instantiating the object

```
>>> print A._attribute
['string',]
```

Memcached is switched on. But in my understanding does not cache these objects, hence can't be responsible

I have never seen anything like that in the past. Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 4):

`_attribute` is attached to the whole class, so all instances will have the same `_attribute` value.

To avoid this, use instance variables

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._attribute = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a class attribute that is mutable. `_attribute` is not a member of an instance, but of class `A` itself. As you're using `extend`, you're changing that value for all instances as long as python is running.